# I'm trying to write the Dictionary - Simplex Method - as in the image. Could someone help me?

Tags: fractions

[image]

I am trying to write something like that (as shown in the image) but I don't know how...

## I'm using this notation:

\begin{equation} 
    \begin{array}{rrc1c1} 
    \multicolumn{4}{1}{} \ 
 
         & s_1 = 6- 2x_1 - 3x_2 \ 
         & s_2 = 3 + 3x_1 - 2x_2 \ 
         & s_3 = 5 + 0x_1 - 2x_2\ 
         & s_4 = 4 - 2x_1 - 1x_2 \ 
         & Z   = 0 - 3x_1 - 4x_2 \ 
    \end{array} 
\end{equation}

However, I don't know how to draw a line as in a fraction. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are potential complications. For one, the equation is bottom aligned, in its current presentation, so the eq number will appear to the right of the `Z=` row (to avoid this, wrap the `\tabbedShortstack` inside a `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`).

Inter-row gap can be increased with `\setstackgap{S}{<gap size>}`.

But without knowing all your use cases, this might work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABbinary
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\tabbedShortstack[r]{
 s_1 =& 6 &- 2x_1 &- 3x_2 \\
 s_2 =& 3 &+ 3x_1 &- 2x_2 \\
 s_3 =& 5 &+ 0x_1 &- 2x_2\\
 s_4 =& 4 &- 2x_1 &- 1x_2 \\
 \TABcline{1-4}
   Z =& 0 &- 3x_1 &- 4x_2 
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here it is again, with eq number centered, and increased row and column gaps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABbinary
\setstackgap{S}{5pt}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\vcenter{\hbox{\tabbedShortstack[r]{
 s_1 =& 6 &- 2x_1 &- 3x_2 \\
 s_2 =& 3 &+ 3x_1 &- 2x_2 \\
 s_3 =& 5 &+ 0x_1 &- 2x_2\\
 s_4 =& 4 &- 2x_1 &- 1x_2 \\
 \TABcline{1-4}
   Z =& 0 &- 3x_1 &- 4x_2 
}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first one didn't work, I'll try the second one. Thanks

Comment: @Rubs You will have to explain what you mean by "did not work".

Comment: Both are giving me the same output: no line and before the Z letter appears "1 - 4"

Comment: @Rubs Did you invoke the package with `\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}`?  Do you have an up to date version `tabstackengine 2018/03/05 (V2.10)`? https://ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine and, if needed https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine (V4.01)

Comment: Yes, I did invoke it. Well I'm using overleaf...

Comment: @Rubs I've never used overleaf.  If you get a log file as part of your output, it should tell you what package versions they are using.  Don't know if they take requests to update packages...